# Is there a way to make a variable width font act like a fixed width font in HTML?

Tags: html, css, typography

Is there a way to make a variable width font act like a fixed width font in HTML?

For example, if I have the sentence, "The quick grey fox jumped over the lazy dog" displayed in "Courier New", a fixed width font, it would be wider overall than if it was in a variable width font like, "Arial". I would like to use "Arial" instead of "Courier New" but have the characters fixed width.

Example of variable width:
The quick grey fox jumped over the lazy dog.

Example of fixed width:

```
The quick grey fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

Notice how close the characters are to each other in the word "quick" and "grey" in each example.

Comment: HTML or TLF? Which one do you want? Those are two completely different rendering technologies which require different solutions.

Comment: That's true. What I'm starting with is a list of text. I can choose either technology to use in this case. But I can create a new question.

Comment: You seem to be getting a lot of HTML answers and I can't think of a quick fix for TLF. So maybe you can base your choice of technology on that.

Comment: It's looking that way. I've created a separate question for TLF since someone visiting this post in the future may find answers for two different technologies confusing.

Comment: The HTML approach may work for TLF as well. I would have to create span elements, and set the width and text alignment of each. Unfortunately, the HTML import in TLF is very very slow (TLF 2.0).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not with just CSS. I would recommend you use the popular [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/) (you'll need jQuery for it) to generate `span` tags around each character, then set an width across all the characters.

```
.monospace > span {
  display: inline-block; /* Enable widths */
  width: 1em;            /* Set width across all characters */
  text-align: center;    /* Even out spacing */
}
```

**[Test Case](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRoYpW)**

Comment: Could I remove the requirement by adding span tags before hand? What does the body {
  font: 16px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif
} do?

Comment: If you want to hand code the `span` tags into the document, that would work also. You do not then need Lettering.js.

The `font` declaration sets a base `font-size` of 16px, a base `line-height` of 1.5em (or 24px) and a `font-family` of Arial, with a backup of sans-serif, on the entire document. It is the shorthand of using all of these properties separately.

Comment: @JoeJ, down voting this because I could not get this to work and the test case no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing I can think of is to put each letter in an HTML element, and style that element something along the lines of:

```
width: 8px;         /* Whatever fixed width you want here */
display: block;     /* Force the width to be respected. See also: inline-block */
float: left;        /* So it won't be 1-per-line. Not needed for inline-block */
text-align: center; /* So the character appears in the middle of the block */
```

I'm not familiar with Flex, but if I were to implement this approach, I would put together some Javascript that would generate all the elements for me.

Comment: Each character is already in it's own span tags so I think this just might work. :)

Comment: This does what the question asks for, but this means that letters do not *look* like evenly spaced; e.g., in “World”, the first two letters seem to be much closer to each other than the rest. The point is that to create monospace impression, you need a real monospace font.

Comment: @AshleyRoss You could use inline-block and get rid of the float. Inline block lets you set a size on an element but displays it inline (no new line).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If the letters are centered and manually set to a width it should look like monospaced. I'd have to see an example.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but I would suggest looking for a suitable fixed-width font that can be used as a webfont that has the features you want.  I'm a pretty big fan of Inconsolata, for example.

I'd start with [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts/) and unselect all categories leaving only Monospace.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the letter-spacing CSS property to get what you want. By definition, monospace fonts have the same character width unlike serif or sans-serif. Using letter-spacing is your best bet [W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-letter-spacing)

Comment: Isn't the letter-spacing value just added to the default kerning for a given font? While it would increase or decrease the spacing between each letter, it won't make the spacing uniform, correct? But if this meets 1.21 gigawatts' needs, it's definitely a better option than my suggestion. :)

Comment: I think Ashley's right. I think it adds or subtracts to the values in the font's kerning table.

Comment: The `letter-spacing` value specifies added spacing between characters (kerning is something completely different), so it would not make the spacing uniform at all.

Comment: I think this is a good point to add, and although not exactly "fixed-width", it might help with a main problem where a fixed-width is desired only because the text is too hard to read bunched up.  So good to mention the `letter-spacing` as a factor to consider

Answer (score 0):

The result should be crappy as proportional fonts aren't made for that.

Nonetheless, you can achieve that with individual `span` around characters: http://jsfiddle.net/rvYES/

```
body {
  font: normal 100%/1.5 Arial;
}

span {
  outline: 1px dotted darkred;
}
span:nth-of-type(even) {
  outline-color: blue;
}

.w-fixed span {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1em;
}
```

I added visual clues (outline) to see what's going on and used `min-width` just in case, not `width`.
This method will cause a huge problem of accessibility with screen readers, for blind and partially sighted people using these assistive technologies. Letters being into individual `span` will be spelled / read out
o
n
e

b
y

o
n
e

w
h
i
l
e

a

n
o
r
m
a
l

p
a
r
a
g
r
a
p
h

w
o
u
l
d

b
e

r
e
a
d

a
s

a

s
e
n
t
e
n
c
e
,

a
s

u
s
u
a
l
.

P
r
e
t
t
y

a
n
n
o
y
i
n
g

e
h
?

*pun intended*

Comment: Typographically the result would be crappy, but there is no reason why screen readers would spell out each letter. (Poor screen readers might do odd things, though.)

Comment: :) What is the CSS in the body tag doing? I've seen it in more than a few places now.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela If you were developing an AT, you could've reasons to behave differently when seeing letters in individual `span` rather than in a normal sentence, though I don't have the test cases from real world that led them to this decision. And if you want to style the first letter from a paragraph, well at least CSS has `:first-letter`

Comment: @1.21gigawatts `font` is the shorthand property for a bunch of `font-something` properties and also `line-height`. Using percentages for `font-size` is due to using `em` unit (not pixels) and a bug of most versions of IE with `em` unit on this particular element http://clagnut.com/blog/348/ (IE is fine with `em`s on any other element...). `/1.5` is the `line-height` value (*unitless*) that will be inherited in the whole document.