# Width of Dates are not the same because width of number 1 and 2 are different?

Tags: css

I am working on a react project, and I list some operations ( objects ) in a Table, everything looks fine but the client for something I found very weird and hard, here is how it looks :

[image]

But that is not how he wanted the datatable dates looks, he wants something like this :

[image]

Is there a CSS property that can make that possible ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

there is too much code to write, but those parts are enough :

HTML :

```
<div class="co-operations-contrat__date">
    <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">04/07/2018</span>
</div>
```

SASS :

```
.co-operations-contrat {
   &__date {
    a {
        margin-right: 5px;
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        +.co-operations-contrat__date-text {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    }
    &-text {
        margin-left: 25px;

        font-family: "Poppins", monospace;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: are you able to simply use a mono-spaced font for those dates?

Comment: are you able to actually add the code? Seeing how its structured would be helpful.

Comment: I am trying to edit my post.

Comment: @Mark how about now ?

Comment: Consider using a monospace font for the dates. https://www.cssfontstack.com/monospace

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149330/force-non-monospace-font-into-fixed-width-using-css

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149330/force-non-monospace-font-into-fixed-width-using-css) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177368/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-variable-width-font-act-like-a-fixed-width-font-in-html)...

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said `monospace` for the dates would be best. If you can't change the font are you able to wrap each part of the date?
If so what you could do is something like this;

https://jsfiddle.net/8mLwot25/3/

Basically, I've set a width on each span and aligned them with flex on the parent container. (You could also float each span). But by doing this would align the items in a better way.

It's not perfect but its a solution.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container span {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
}

.container span:last-child {
  width: auto;
}
```

```
<div class="container">
  <span>01</span>/
  <span>04</span>/
  <span>2019</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span>01</span>/
  <span>05</span>/
  <span>2018</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span>13</span>/
  <span>04</span>/
  <span>2019</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [letter-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) can help you with that. I'm not sure if you can achieve a pixel perfect result with that but this property may be usefull.

Comment: I thought of that, but I will have to treat each case alone, it is hard work, I will have to treat case where my date contains 3 or 4 numbers 1 like " 11/11/2011" and "12/11/2011" .. letter spacing does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the `Poppins` font you are using for these dates.  The font is not monospaced (it is sans-serif only).

If using a regular `monospace` font, the issue no longer appears

**See demo below**

```css
.co-operations-contrat__date a {
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.co-operations-contrat__date .co-operations-contrat__date-text {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.co-operations-contrat__date-text {
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-family: "Poppins", monospace;
}

#no-poppins .co-operations-contrat__date-text {
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">

<h2>Poppins In</h2>
<div class="co-operations-contrat__date">
  <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">30/06/2018</span><br/>
  <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">31/03/2018</span><br/>
  <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">04/07/2018</span><br/>
  <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">31/01/2011</span><br/>
</div>

<h2>Poppins Out</h2>
<div id="no-poppins" class="co-operations-contrat__date">
  <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">30/06/2018</span><br/>
  <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">31/03/2018</span><br/>
  <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">04/07/2018</span><br/>
  <span class="co-operations-contrat__date-text">31/01/2011</span><br/>
</div>

<h1>Other workarounds include </h1>

<h2>Usign &lt;TT&gt;</h2>
<div class="co-operations-contrat__date">
  <tt>30/06/2018</tt><br/>
  <tt>31/03/2018</tt><br/>
  <tt>04/07/2018</tt><br/>
  <tt>31/01/2011</tt><br/>
</div>

<h2>Using &lt;PRE&gt;</h2>
<div class="co-operations-contrat__date">
  <span>30/06/2018</pre>
  <pre>31/03/2018</pre>
  <pre>04/07/2018</pre>
  <pre>31/01/2011</pre>
</div>
```

Of course, you can choose any `monospaced` font of your choosing, I just went the browser's defaults for the demo.

Comment: I need to use that font, .. Thank you Sir

Comment: @TaouBen for all dates? then there is no answer, per se.  Only workarounds or hacks... can you find a similar font but monospaced?